# How to make continuos opening animation in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation

How to make a cool and simple opening animation in html,css,js

I have tried this but this did not work:-

html code

```
<div class="Anim">
   <div>Header</div>
</div>
```

Css code:-

```
.Anim {
   position: absolute;
   top: -100px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: purple;
   color: red;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 50px;
   border: 3px solid lime;
}
```

Javascript code:-

```
function anim() {
   let elem = document.querySelector('.Anim');
   let y = -100;
   setTimeout(inner(),1000);

   function inner() {
      if(y == 0) {
          return;
      }
      else {
          y++;
          elem.style.top = y + 'px';
          setTimeout(inner(),1000);
      }
   }
}

anim();
```

Is their a way to fix this and make it work, **if any please let me know**.

***Thankyou in avance***

Comment: We would need to also see the relevant HTML and CSS, along with a description of the animation effect you're trying to create (if it's not obvious enough from the state of the code) in order to help you. Also note it's `setTimeout()`, not `setTimout()` and that you should pass the function *reference* not the *return value* to `setTimeout()`, ie. `setTimeout(inner, 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the parenthesis for `setTimeout(inner(), 1000)`

```
function anim() {
   let elem = document.querySelector('.Anim');
   let y = -100;
   setTimeout(inner ,1000);

   function inner() {
      if(y == 0) {
          return;
      }
      else {
          y++;
          elem.style.top = y + 'px';
          setTimeout(inner(),1000);
      }
   }
}

anim();
```

There is also a more efficient way of doing it by using `@keyframes`